# Create a protocol using two classes

Tags: swift, macos, serialization, deserialization, protocols

I have two classes, something like that

```
class FirstClass {
```

`func returnInt() -> Int {
       return (42)
   }
}

class SecondClass {

   func printInt(myInt: Int) {
    print(myInt)
   }
}`

I would like to know if it is possible to create a Protocol when the function "returnInt() -> Int" of the FirstClass is call so the function of the second Class "printInt(Int)" is call.

In reality, I'm working on the serialization / deserialization of packet from different classes.

I think is the best way for that, that's why I need your help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Closures

I don't know your exact usage, but one way is using closures instead of protocols. Create closure variable inside first class and then call it after value is returned

```
class FirstClass {

    var valueReturned: ((Int)->Void)?

    func returnInt() -> Int {
        let value = 42
        valueReturned?(value)
        return value
    }
}
```

then somewhere where you have references for both instances of both classes set first's `valueReturned` and inside closure say that when this will be called, you want to call `printInt(myInt:)` of second's and as parameter pass value from closure

```
firstClass.valueReturned = { value in // assign parameter of closure
    self.secondClass.printInt(myInt: value)
    // self.printInt(myInt: value)
}
```

---

#### Delegate Patern

Anyway, if you want to use protocols, you'll need delegate patern.

Start with declaring protocol

```
protocol FirstClassDelegate: class {
    func printInt(myInt: Int)
}
```

and then create delegate variable inside first class and call method on delegate after value should be returned

```
class FirstClass {

    weak var delegate: FirstClassDelegate?

    func returnInt() -> Int {
        let value = 42
        delegate?.printInt(myInt: value)
        return value
    }
}
```

Now implement this delegate protocol to second class and set `delegate` property of some first class instance as `self`

```
class SecondClass {

    var firstClass = FirstClass()

    init() {
        firstClass.delegate = self
    }
}

extension SecondClass: FirstClassDelegate {
    func printInt(myInt: Int) {
        print(myInt)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
class FirstClass {

    weak var firstClassToSecondClassCommunicatorDelegate: FirstClassToSecondClassCommunicator?

    func returnInt() -> Int {
        let myInt = 42
        if firstClassToSecondClassCommunicatorDelegate != nil {
            firstClassToSecondClassCommunicatorDelegate?.printInt(myInt: myInt)
        }
        return myInt
    }
}

class SecondClass: FirstClassToSecondClassCommunicator {
    func printInt(myInt: Int) {
        print(myInt)
    }
}

class myVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let firstClass = FirstClass()
        let secondClass = SecondClass()
        firstClass.firstClassToSecondClassCommunicatorDelegate = secondClass
    }
}

protocol FirstClassToSecondClassCommunicator {
    func printInt(myInt: Int)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In secondClass initialize your class with:

```
init(fromFirstClass returnInt: Int) {
    ....
}
```